# Can't Get JSON Parsed from HTTP Response

Tags: json, go, http-get

So, I'm trying to figure out how to get the following code to properly parse the JSON data from https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum. It seems to have no problem decoding the JSON data in the response from http://echo.jsontest.com/key1/value1/key2/value2, but only gets empty/zero values when pointed at the CoinMarketCap API.

```
package main

import(
  "encoding/json"
  "net/http"
  "log"
)

type JsonTest struct {
  Key1  string
  Key2  string
}

type CoinMarketCapData struct {
  Id               string
  Name             string
  Symbol           string
  Rank             int
  PriceUSD         float64
  PriceBTC         float64
  Volume24hUSD     float64
  MarketCapUSD     float64
  AvailableSupply   float64
  TotalSupply       float64
  PercentChange1h   float32
  PercentChange24h float32
  PercentChange7d   float32
}

func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
  client := &http.Client{}
  req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
  req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  r, err := client.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  defer r.Body.Close()
  return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}

func main() {
  //Test with dummy JSON
  url1 := "http://echo.jsontest.com/key1/value1/key2/value2"
  jsonTest := new(JsonTest)
  getJson(url1, jsonTest)
  log.Printf("jsonTest Key1: %s", jsonTest.Key1)

  //Test with CoinMarketCap JSON
  url2 := "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum"
  priceData := new(CoinMarketCapData)
  getJson(url2, priceData)
  //Should print "Ethereum Id: ethereum"
  log.Printf("Ethereum Id: %s", priceData.Id)
}
```

I suspect it's related to the fact that the JSON at CoinMarketCap is inside a top level JSON array, but I've tried various iterations of things like:

```
priceData := make([]CoinMarketCapData, 1)
```

to no avail. Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is an array, so you need to pass an array to the Decode method. Also remember to check the returned error.

```
package main

import(
  "encoding/json"
  "net/http"
  "log"
)

type CoinMarketCapData struct {
  Id               string
  Name             string
  Symbol           string
  Rank             int
  PriceUSD         float64
  PriceBTC         float64
  Volume24hUSD     float64
  MarketCapUSD     float64
  AvailableSupply   float64
  TotalSupply       float64
  PercentChange1h   float32
  PercentChange24h float32
  PercentChange7d   float32
}

func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
  client := &http.Client{}
  req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
  req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  r, err := client.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  defer r.Body.Close()
  return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}

func main() {
  //Test with CoinMarketCap JSON
  url2 := "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum"
  priceData := make([]CoinMarketCapData, 0)
  err := getJson(url2, &priceData)
  if err != nil {
     log.Printf("Failed to decode json: %v", err)
  } else {
    //Should print "Ethereum Id: ethereum"
    log.Printf("Ethereum Id: %v", priceData[0].Id)
  }
}
```

running this prints

```
2016/08/21 17:15:27 Ethereum Id: ethereum
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the top level API response type is a list and that has to be reflected in the unmarshalling process. One way to fix this would be to define your *MarketCap* response as slice, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// curl -sLf "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum" | JSONGen
// command line helper: `go get github.com/bemasher/JSONGen`
type MarketCapResponse []struct {
    AvailableSupply  float64 `json:"available_supply"`
    HVolumeUsd       float64 `json:"24h_volume_usd"`
    Id               string  `json:"id"`
    MarketCapUsd     float64 `json:"market_cap_usd"`
    Name             string  `json:"name"`
    PercentChange1h  float64 `json:"percent_change_1h"`
    PercentChange24h float64 `json:"percent_change_24h"`
    PercentChange7d  float64 `json:"percent_change_7d"`
    PriceBtc         float64 `json:"price_btc"`
    PriceUsd         float64 `json:"price_usd"`
    Rank             int64   `json:"rank"`
    Symbol           string  `json:"symbol"`
    TotalSupply      float64 `json:"total_supply"`
}
```

Then the unmarshaling would work just fine. One thing to note is that pointer to a slice is different from the slice. Especially, the pointer does not support indexing, which is why need to dereference it first to access the first item in the list.

```
func getAndUnmarshal(url string, target interface{}) error {
    var client = &http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    r, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}

func main() {
    link := "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum"
    resp := new(MarketCapResponse)
    getAndUnmarshal(link, resp)
    log.Printf("Ethereum Id: %s", (*resp)[0].Id)
    // prints:
    // 2016/08/22 02:13:23 Ethereum Id: ethereum
}
```

---

Another way would be to define a type for a single *MarketCap* and then create a slice as a target when needed:

```
package main

// curl -sLf "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum" | jq .[0] | JSONGen
type MarketCap struct {
    AvailableSupply  float64 `json:"available_supply"`
    HVolumeUsd       float64 `json:"24h_volume_usd"`
    Id               string  `json:"id"`
    MarketCapUsd     float64 `json:"market_cap_usd"`
    Name             string  `json:"name"`
    PercentChange1h  float64 `json:"percent_change_1h"`
    PercentChange24h float64 `json:"percent_change_24h"`
    PercentChange7d  float64 `json:"percent_change_7d"`
    PriceBtc         float64 `json:"price_btc"`
    PriceUsd         float64 `json:"price_usd"`
    Rank             int64   `json:"rank"`
    Symbol           string  `json:"symbol"`
    TotalSupply      float64 `json:"total_supply"`
}

func getAndUnmarshal(url string, target interface{}) error {
     ...
}

func main() {
    link := "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum"
    resp := make([]MarketCap, 0)
    getAndUnmarshal(link, &resp)
    log.Printf("Ethereum Id: %s", resp[0].Id)
    // 2016/08/22 02:13:23 Ethereum Id: ethereum
}
```

What is more suitable for you will depend on your use case. If you want the struct to reflect the API response, then the first approach seems more suitable. Is *MarketCap* a thing and the API is just one way to access it, than the second fits better, I believe.